# Can ML.NET parse/load .tfrecord files?

Tags: tensorflow-datasets, ml.net

I’ve been looking at some open Tensorflow datasets, and was wondering if I can use ML.NET to parse the .tfrecord files and export the schema.

I haven’t found anything saying ML.NET can support this, but curious if anyone knows of an existing approach using C#?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, it currently doesn't. There is [an issue](https://github.com/SciSharp/TensorFlow.NET/issues/262) in the TensorFlow.NET repository to support .tfrecord files so once that happens ML.NET can consume it.